# Error trying to call .buildClassifier (Weka) in Java AndroidStudio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, weka

I am trying to use Weka in Android Studio. And I am stuck at the this line:

```
linearRegresion.buildClassifier(data);
```

Its red underlined and it says:

> Unhandled Exception:Java.lang.Exception

I was trying other ways and with different dataSet and its allways underlined at .buildClassifier

```
    //test:
    NaiveBayes nB = new NaiveBayes();
    nB.buildClassifier(dataSet); //Unhandled exception

    Classifier cModel = (Classifier)new LinearRegression();
    cModel.buildClassifier(data); //Unhandled exception
```

Trying to fix this for hours, couldn't find solution on internet,I think I am just missing something maybe I just need to Import something more?

I was doing this from the tutorial so the code should work. Tutorial: 
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-weka3/index.html

**Whole code**

```
import weka.*;
import weka.classifiers.trees.J48;
import weka.core.*;
import weka.classifiers.Classifier;
import weka.core.Instance;
import weka.core.Instances;
import weka.classifiers.functions.LinearRegression;
import weka.classifiers.bayes.NaiveBayes;

public class Meni extends Activity {
public void Weka(){
    //@ATTRIBUTE houseSize NUMERIC
    Attribute a1 = new Attribute("houseSize", 0);
    Attribute a2 = new Attribute("lotSize", 1);
    Attribute a3 = new Attribute("bedrooms", 2);
    Attribute a4 = new Attribute("granite", 3);
    Attribute a5 = new Attribute("bathroom", 4);
    Attribute a6 = new Attribute("sellingPrice", 5);

    //ArrayList attr = new ArrayList();
    FastVector attrs = new FastVector();
    attrs.addElement(a1);
    attrs.addElement(a2);
    attrs.addElement(a3);
    attrs.addElement(a4);
    attrs.addElement(a5);
    attrs.addElement(a6);

    //@DATA
    Instance i1  = new DenseInstance(6);
    i1.setValue(a1, 3529);
    i1.setValue(a2, 9191);
    i1.setValue(a3, 6);
    i1.setValue(a4, 0);
    i1.setValue(a5, 0);
    i1.setValue(a6, 205000);
    Instance i2  = new DenseInstance(6);
    i2.setValue(a1, 3247);
    i2.setValue(a2, 10061);
    i2.setValue(a3, 5);
    i2.setValue(a4, 1);
    i2.setValue(a5, 1);
    i2.setValue(a6, 224900);
    Instance i3  = new DenseInstance(6);
    i3.setValue(a1, 4032);
    i3.setValue(a2, 10150);
    i3.setValue(a3, 5);
    i3.setValue(a4, 0);
    i3.setValue(a5, 1);
    i3.setValue(a6, 197900);

    //set class Atribute
    dataSet.setClassIndex(dataSet.numAttributes()-1);

    //Creating model
    LinearRegression linearRegresion = new LinearRegression();
    linearRegresion.buildClassifier(data); //Unhandled exception :(
```

}
}

Comment: You need to handle the exception using a try/catch. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/handling.html

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to put that inside. Now I get this exception:

_06-13 20:26:30.456  23171-23171/com.example.wheresmymoney E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.wheresmymoney, PID: 23171
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment
        ....._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was problem with weka.jar library. Normal one that I download from weka site is not working with android.Now I downloaded modified one from user rjmanrsan:
https://github.com/rjmarsan/Weka-for-Android
Working now :)